# RestResource to convert Apex-Defined Data Type for Flow Interview

Tags: apex, rest-api, visual-workflow, aura-enabled

I am attempting to use Flow as a low-code API development platform. The plan is to expose an endpoint with a RestResource, convert the request to an Apex-Defined variable, pass to a Flow and let the flow manage the business logic and return the (or another) Apex-Defined variable as the response.

Two questions

1. Is this a practical use case or pattern?
2. Can you help me put together a simple GET PoC?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/Object')
global class ObjectWS {

    @HttpGet
    global static void get() {   
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;    
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        try {
            // Configure the response structure in this object
            res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            // Received data
            String Id = req.params.get('Id');
            
            // Instantiate MyObject and set the ID 
            
            // Query for the Customer Order using the provided Order ID
            params.put('MyObject', MyObject);
            Flow.Interview.ObjectAPI_GET APIFlow = new Flow.Interview.ObjectAPI_GET(params);
            APIFlow.start();

    }
}
```

The the APIFlow would receive this, potentially query the various objects it needs and then return an updated version of the variable that I assume can be converted back to JSON for the API response.

Comment: Flow input / output is just a map of key:value pairs and I don't see why the value couldn't be of some ApexType (outer classes only). Just note there's no introspection in case you need multiple input apextypes yielding multiple output apextypes - the documentation on flow and apextypes is more geared at flow invoking apex but flow variables can be apextypes

Comment: @cropredy is there at least a way to cast an Apex-Defined variable as a sObject? For example if I assign values to my var and retrieve like so `myVar var = (myVar) myFlow.getVariableValue('myFlowVar'); I want to then add it to _(sObject)_ `myResponse.body`. If I serialize it comes as string with "\" throughout.

Comment: @cropredy I also tried `String myVar = String.valueOf(api.getVariableValue('myFlowVar'));` but again the API response now is fully of unwanted slashes

Comment: Apex types are never an instance of sobject so direct casting won't be possible.

Comment: note: an apex type that looks like the result of a GET REST object query can be JSON serialized (not cast) to an sobject

Comment: @cropredy how do I do that without all the extra "\" in my response. At the moment if I serialize `myVar` in Postman I'm seeing a long string with "\" at the beginning and end of every parameter and value, like so: `{\"param\":\"value\", ... }`

Comment: I'm sort of losing the thread here ... perhaps ask a different question with a concrete example of the REST payload received by the end point and the desired output of the apex type

Comment: @cropredy I've captured this as a new question here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/372066/apex-defined-data-type-for-restful-response