# Apex Defined Data Type for RESTful Response

Tags: apex, rest-api, visual-workflow

I currently have a Flow that manages the logic of my simple GET API request

**Endpoint** `...services/apexrest/{{version}}/CustomerOrders/{{OrderNumber}}`

The `RestResource` manages the routing to call my "**CustomerOrderAPI - GET**" Flow and provides it with a `CustomerOrder` apex-defined data type.

[image: CustomerOrderAPI - GET Flow]

This flow is complete by assigning details to my `APIResponse` apex-define data type like so

[image: APIResponse Assignment Step]

***Note:** At the moment the body is a `CustomerOrder` data type so that I can provide the response details within Flow invocable variable. Ideally I would love this to be generic but [cropredy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/cropredy) mentions in [my previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371119/restresource-to-convert-apex-defined-data-type-for-flow-interview?noredirect=1#comment538616_371119) that this is not possible*

Therefore I'm content making the `body` a *String* data type not accessible in the Flow UI, and then retrieving my apex-defined data type in the apex and storing it in the body serialized like so:

```
CustomerOrder myObject = (CustomerOrder) api.getVariableValue('aCustomerOrder');
CustomerOrderResponse response = (CustomerOrderResponse) api.getVariableValue('aResponse');

response.body = JSON.serialize(myObject)
```

This made sense to me but unfortunately I'm getting the following body back with "\" throughout.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfully retrieved Customer Order #00######",
    "body": "{\"workOrder\":\"test\",\"technicians\":null,\"startDate\":null,\"saleItems\":null,\"purchaseItems\":null,\"poNumber\":null,\"orderNumber\":\"00######\",\"endDate\":null,\"account\":{\"name\":\"Test Account\",\"id\":\"{{account_id}}\"}}"
}
```

Any ideas as to why or how I can avoid this to get my expected result?

Comment: Clearly the string contains JSON text, but of course being a string any contained JSON text is escaped when rendered to JSON. The typical way to return an arbitrary JSON document (that has an object at the document root) from Apex is to use `Map<String, Object>`, where the keys are strings and the values are primitive values, arrays or further maps. I have no idea if you can adopt this in a flow; it would be interesting to find out.

Comment: Also worth noting that an SObject can be serialised to JSON and deserialized back into a `Map<String, Object>`.